# Why elapsed time is 0 but response code is 200 in jmeter with JDBC request

Tags: java, jmeter, elapsedtime

Elapsed time is showing 0, but response is coming back as 200 ok. What does this mean? I am also getting data back in the response.
[image: C request]
[image]

Details:

1. Running performance test for a stored proc with 10threads/sec,
   Rampup=10, for 15 mins duration
2. In my test for one request there
   are #Samples= 1551, in that 466 samples came with elapsed time 0.

[image: Thread Group Configuration]
[image: sql connection configuration]
[image: Test Plan Configuration]

Comment: Please create [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Added more details to my initial post.

Comment: How long are you expecting the query to take?

Comment: They are fairly quick, here is an example of same request in different environment with more threads: Total # sample: 2903, Average time: 0.057 secs, Max: 0.574, Min: 0.009 Secs